# Faster way to run a million regression models

Tags: r, loops, split, regression, apply

I work with genomic data I often need to run a million or more regression models. The loop I have below works, but is slow, and continues to get slower the longer it goes, from the overhead of appending each new record.

```
#### setup sample data ###
require(data.table)
data <- data.frame(
  C = rnorm(10, 5),
  D = rnorm(10, 7),
  E = rnorm(10, 9),
  A = rnorm(10, 1),
  B = rnorm(10, 3)
)
outcome <- c(rnorm(10, 5))
cov <- data.frame(cov1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2))
#### initialize results file ###
myresults <- data.table(NULL)
#### Run regression against same covariates and outcome for each column in data ##
for (i in 1:ncol(data)) {
  id = colnames(data)[i]
  mydata <- cbind(cov, outcome, data[, id])
  colnames(mydata)[ncol(mydata)] <- id #I can't figure out how to not have to do this
  fit <-
    glm(formula(paste0("outcome ~ as.factor(cov1) + ", id)), data = mydata)
  myresults <- rbindlist(list(
    myresults,
    data.table(
      id = id,
      estimate = signif(coef(summary(fit))[id, "Estimate"], digits = 4),
      pvalue = signif(coef(summary(fit))[id, "Pr(>|t|)"], digits = 4)
    )
  ))
}
myresults
```

This gives my output results file that is exactly what I need. I can modify this to add in other output, run additional models in the loop to stratify by a covariate and then capture etc...  My output always has the same number of rows of data as their were columns in my initial `data`.

```
   id estimate  pvalue
1:  C -0.22220 0.49230
2:  D  0.64550 0.08568
3:  E -0.06756 0.83990
4:  A  0.39750 0.54060
5:  B -0.34300 0.35410
```

I was able to gain some improvement by the switch to `data.table::rbindlist` that you see in the loop.

I have been trying to use something like `lapply(split(data, colnames(data)))` to see if I can speed this up more, and maybe even use `mclapply()`, but have been unable to get it to work.

Help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  I Upvoted all who responded as they were all helpful and I appreciate the time taken.

The clear winner by a 6 fold margin was Roland's Comment. I'm listing what I did here for posterity and in case it can help someone else.

I merged into a very wide dataset ( 260 x 470,000)

```
require(data.table)
require(reshape2)
bigdata <- cbind(mycovs, testdata)
test <- data.table(bigdata)
```

I then made it a tall dataset:

```
    DT.m1 = melt(
  test,
  id.vars = c(
    "Sample_Plate",
    "BaseName",
    "Race",
    "Education",
    "mom_age_delv",
    "sex",
    "gest_age_wks",
    "MONTH_OLD",
    "DEPRESSION",
    "CD8T",
    "CD4T",
    "NK",
    "Bcell",
    "Mono",
    "Gran"
  ),
  measure.vars = c(16:ncol(test)),
  variable.name = "cpg",
  value.name = "betaval"
)
```

I then ran my full regression model and pulled out the last row from the coefficients table as follow:

```
system.time(res <-
              DT.m1[, {
                fit <-
                  glm(
                    DEPRESSION ~ as.factor(Sample_Plate) + as.factor(sex) + as.factor(Education) + as.factor(Race) + MONTH_OLD + mom_age_delv + gest_age_wks + CD8T + CD4T + NK + Bcell + Mono + Gran + betaval,
                    data = .SD
                  )
                coef(summary(fit))[nrow(coef(summary(fit))), c(1, 2, 4)]
              }, by = cpg])
```

Lastly, I cleaned it up.

```
res <- cbind(res, c("beta1", "se", "pvalue"))
head(res)
final_results <- dcast(data = res, cpg ~ V2, value.var = "V1")[c(1, 2, 4, 3)]
```

This resulted in a time of ~ 10 seconds per 1000 models.  The next closes thing was ~ 60 seconds.

The cleanup portion seems like it should be able to be done in data.table(), but I was unable to figure it out. I could only get a tall 2 column vector repeated for each of the coef columns I requested.

If you have other ideas on how to improve, please let me know and thanks again.

Comment: You might look into parallelism, multicore, and GPU strategies, etc. This is a little broad for Stack Overflow though. You might want to try the Code Review SE. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This looks really dubious. You can probably do something more sensible than producing these useless p-values. Anyway, first step: make your data a data.table and reshape to long format, second step: DT[, {fit <- glm(outcome ~ ., data = .SD); <more code>; <list of coefficients and p-values>}, by = variable]. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Roland. Regarding validity, read up on GWAS SNP testing or CpG methylation mark testing and using adjusted pvalues and qqplots to determine significance; we can have a sidebar chat sometime if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `myresults <- rbindlist(list(myresults, ...))`, you're copying the entirety of `myresults`, modifying the copy, and then having the name point to the copy. The most common cause of inefficient looping in R is "growing an object". You know the exact dimensions of the result (`ncol(data)` by 3), so just make it to begin with. And then use `data.table` to assign by reference (no copying).

See if this helps improve efficiency:

```
#### initialize results file ###
myresults <- data.table(
  id       = character(length(data)),
  estimate = numeric(  length(data)),
  pvalue   = numeric(  length(data))
)

#### Run regression against same covariates and outcome for each column in data ##
for (i in seq_along(data)) {
  id = colnames(data)[i]
  mydata <- cbind(cov, outcome, data[, id])
  colnames(mydata)[ncol(mydata)] <- id #I can't figure out how to not have to do this
  fit <-
    glm(formula(paste0("outcome ~ as.factor(cov1) + ", id)), data = mydata)
  set(
    myresults,
    i     = i,
    j     = c("id", "estimate", "pvalue"),
    value = list(
      id       = id,
      estimate = signif(coef(summary(fit))[id, "Estimate"], digits = 4),
      pvalue   = signif(coef(summary(fit))[id, "Pr(>|t|)"], digits = 4)
    )
  )
}
```

I also replaced `for (i in 1:ncol(data))` with `for (i in seq_along(data))`, because the first way behaves in a bad way when `data` has no columns. You might think it'll never happen, but writing loops that way is a bad habit.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. It took a few seconds longer per 1000 models in the beginning of the run, but the speed was constant throughout, and greatly improved the overall time.  The data.table method I posted ended up making the object too large after making a tall dataset with all my covariates as well. This method ended up allowing me to run ~500k models in less than 3 hours. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but seeing as I am a sucker for optimization...

The OP's updated solution has them nesting their results in a `data.table`; basically running each regression by a grouped variable. This is a good strategy, not least because `data.table` will automatically take care of parallelism for you.

However, you are still asking R to do a lot more work than it needs to by running a full `glm()` call each time. You only need the coefficients (and se + p-values). All the other stuff that `glm()` includes — the model.matrix etc. — is just wasted effort and memory overhead. Not only that, but it's not clear to me why you are running a *generalised* model in the first place, since you aren't calling a non-Gaussian family (binomial, etc.) Calling a standard linear model (i.e. `lm()`) will automatically reduce overhead too.

So, what's the solution? Switch to matrix arrays and use **`lm.fit()`** instead. This is the workhorse function that `lm()` calls underneath the hood and is much leaner/faster. In fact, there's an even leaner/faster `.lm.fit()` version, but that will make it a little tricky to to calculate SEs + p-values. (More on this below.) Quick benchmarks on a single regression adapted from the OP's MWE:

```r
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(
    C = rnorm(10, 5),
    D = rnorm(10, 7),
    E = rnorm(10, 9),
    A = rnorm(10, 1),
    B = rnorm(10, 3)
)
outcome <- c(rnorm(10, 5))
cov <- data.frame(cov1 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)))

id = "A"
mydata = cbind(cov, outcome, x = data[, id])
# design matrix for *.fit versions
X = cbind(intercept = 1, cov1 = cov$cov1, x = data[, id])

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    .lm.fit = .lm.fit(X, outcome),
    lm.fit  = lm.fit(X, outcome),
    glm.fit = glm.fit(X, outcome),
    lm      = lm(outcome ~ cov1 + x, data = mydata),
    glm     = glm(outcome ~ cov1 + x, data = mydata),
    times   = 100
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>     expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
#>  .lm.fit   1.684   3.479   4.92692   4.1815   4.8915   33.607   100 a   
#>   lm.fit  16.222  24.195  27.62058  27.5270  30.4225   51.694   100 a   
#>  glm.fit 135.641 149.130 195.54319 164.6615 179.8900 1920.694   100  b  
#>       lm 531.621 554.632 658.56501 632.0585 663.1655 2552.081   100   c 
#>      glm 702.767 724.999 855.46429 850.9145 863.4710 2418.207   100    d
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

So you'd get a 30–200x (!) speed-up simply by using a leaner array type (matrices) and regression call (`lm.fit`/`.lm.fit`). Note that you can still use the nested data.table approach with matrix objects to get the best of both worlds. That takes a bit more explaining, but you can see an example [here](https://grantmcdermott.com/efficient-simulations-in-r/#principle-4-use-matrices-for-an-extra-edge).

**Postscript** Getting Standard errors and p-values from `lm.fit` objects.

The only slight complication with the `lm.fit` approach and the OP's desired output is that we don't get SEs and p-values automatically. However, it's easy to write our own function (lifted almost verbatim from `summary.lm`) that does this for us.

```r
se_pval = function(object) {
    z <- object
    p <- z$rank
    rdf <- z$df.residual
    Qr <- z$qr
    r = z$residuals
    rss <- sum(r^2)
    resvar <- rss/rdf
    p1 <- 1L:p
    R <- chol2inv(Qr$qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE])
    se <- sqrt(diag(R) * resvar)
    est <- z$coefficients[Qr$pivot[p1]]
    tval <- est/se
    pval = 2 * pt(abs(tval), rdf, lower.tail = FALSE)
    se_pval = rbind(se, pval); names(se_pval) = colnames(pval)
    return(se_pval)
}


fit = lm.fit(X, outcome)
c(coef(fit)['x'], se_pval(fit)[, 'x'])
#>         x        se      pval 
#> 0.5784677 0.3230284 0.1164475

## Compare with glm.summary
coef(summary(glm(outcome ~ cov1 + x, data = mydata)))['x', c(1,2,4)]
#>   Estimate Std. Error   Pr(>|t|) 
#>  0.5784677  0.3230284  0.1164475
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**UPDATE**

Adding in a fully worked iteration as requested in the comments.

```r
se_pval = function(object) {
    z <- object
    p <- z$rank
    rdf <- z$df.residual
    Qr <- z$qr
    r = z$residuals
    rss <- sum(r^2)
    resvar <- rss/rdf
    p1 <- 1L:p
    R <- chol2inv(Qr$qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE])
    se <- sqrt(diag(R) * resvar)
    est <- z$coefficients[Qr$pivot[p1]]
    tval <- est/se
    pval = 2 * pt(abs(tval), rdf, lower.tail = FALSE)
    se_pval = rbind(se, pval); names(se_pval) = colnames(pval)
    return(se_pval)
}


set.seed(42)
Xlist <- list(
    C = rnorm(10, 5),
    D = rnorm(10, 7),
    E = rnorm(10, 9),
    A = rnorm(10, 1),
    B = rnorm(10, 3)
)
outcome <- c(rnorm(10, 5))
cov1 = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2))

regs = lapply(
    names(Xlist),
    function(id) {
        X = cbind(intercept = 1, cov1 = cov1, x = Xlist[[id]])
        fit  = lm.fit(X, outcome)
        # c(id = id, coef(fit)['x'], se_pval(fit)[, 'x']) ## Could add ID here..
        c(coef(fit)['x'], se_pval(fit)[, 'x'])
        })
regs = signif(do.call("rbind", regs), digits = 4) ## numeric matrix

## Easy to add ID after the fact and coerce to e.g. a data.frame
regs = data.frame(id = names(Xlist), regs)
#>   id       x     se   pval
#> 1  C -0.4300 0.4957 0.4145
#> 2  D  0.1251 0.2590 0.6439
#> 3  E  0.4782 0.4680 0.3409
#> 4  A  0.5785 0.3230 0.1164
#> 5  B  0.1131 0.5511 0.8432
```

Comment: Thanks for the followup.  I'll test this some. I've come up with other solutions where I just flip matrices myself that are the fastest.   Your solution here though skips over the fact that one of the important things to optimize is also the storing of the results (literally millions) and the IO involved in doing so.  right?

Comment: Yes, that's right... although the memory overhead of storing these results will be minimal since everything is so lean. If it were me, I'd put all of my potential explanatory variables in a big matrix or list, then iterate over (or randomly sample) the columns to pull in the design matrix for each particular iteration. I'll update my answer to give an example.

Answer (score 2):

You should give `map` and `map_df` a try

```
library(tidyverse)
myfun <- function(data, outcome, cov) {
    require(tidyverse)
      numcol <- ncol(data)
    newdata <- data %>%
                mutate(outcome = outcome, cov = cov$cov1)

    fmla <- map(names(newdata[,1:numcol]), ~glm(formula(paste0("outcome ~ as.factor(cov) + ", .x)), data=newdata))
    ans <- map_df(fmla, ~as_tibble(matrix(coef(summary(.x))[2, c(1,4)], ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)), .id="id") %>%
               rename(estimate=V1, pvalue=V2)
}
```

#### benchmark

with bigger data

```
biggerdata <- as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(2000), nrow=10))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(myfun(biggerdata,outcome,cov), OP(biggerdata,outcome,cov))

Unit: milliseconds
                            expr      min         lq       mean     median
 myfun(biggerdata, outcome, cov)   71.534   72.98252   77.82994   76.31598
    OP(biggerdata, outcome, cov) 1936.986 1994.03518 2048.96934 2018.33299
         uq       max neval
   79.97554  106.9852   100
 2085.44655 2297.3878   100
```

#### OP function

```
OP <- function(data, outcome, cov) {
    myresults <- data.table(NULL)
    #### Run regression against same covariates and outcome for each column in data ##
    for (i in 1:ncol(data)) {
        id = colnames(data)[i]
        mydata <- cbind(cov, outcome, data[, id])
        colnames(mydata)[ncol(mydata)] <- id #I can't figure out how to not have to do this
        fit <- glm(formula(paste0("outcome ~ as.factor(cov1) + ", id)), data = mydata)
        myresults <- rbindlist(list(
                        myresults,
                        data.table(
                              id = id,
                              estimate = signif(coef(summary(fit))[id, "Estimate"], digits = 4),
                              pvalue = signif(coef(summary(fit))[id, "Pr(>|t|)"], digits = 4)
                        )
        ))
    }
    myresults
}
```

#### new function to handle multiple covariates in cov

```
set.seed(20)
newcov <- data.frame(cov1 = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace=TRUE),
            cov2 = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace=TRUE),
            cov3 = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace=TRUE))

mynewfun <- function(data, outcome, cov) {
                require(tidyverse)
                numcol <- ncol(data)
                newdata <- data %>%
                        mutate(outcome = outcome) %>%
                          cbind(cov)

                covname <- names(cov)
                fmla <- map(names(newdata[,1:numcol]), ~glm(formula(paste0("outcome ~ ", paste0(covname, collapse=" + "), " + ", .x)), data=newdata))
                ans <- map_df(fmla, ~as_tibble(matrix(coef(summary(.x))[2, c(1,4)], ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)), .id="id") %>%
                       rename(estimate=V1, pvalue=V2)
                return(ans)
         }

mynewfun(data,outcome,newcov)
```

Comment: Each column of `data` should be a term on the RHS of `~` (by iteration).  I am working through the syntax, but it looks like the iteration over the columns of `data` are being modeled as independent variable? I want `outcome ~ allcovariates + data[,i]`    Or am I way off base on reading your code?

Comment: I was a bit confused about that. What do you mean by `allcovariates`? You have a single column `cov1` in `cov`. I thought you wanted to make the following formula `outcome ~ cov$cov1 + data[,i]` for each `data[,i]`.

Comment: I just used a single covariate for the example. My model looks like this: `fit <- glm(formula(paste0(outcome, " ~ as.factor(cov1) + as.factor(cov2) + cov3", data[,i])), data=data) `  where the covariates are static, as is the outcome. The variable part are each of the columns of the big data table called `data`. There are literally 467,000 columns of data that I need to fit one at at time.  In truth the outcome variable and all covariates are in one dataset since they are static, and the big data set is separate.

Comment: Do you have time for a chatroom?

Comment: See if the update answer (see function at bottom) does what you expect

Comment: Very close.  I changed to : `  ans <- map_df(fmla, ~as_tibble(matrix(coef(summary(.x))[nrow(coef(summary(.x))), c(1,3,4)], ncol=3, byrow=TRUE),test="pick"), .id ="id")
  return(ans)`   can't figure out how to get a 4th column to be the name of the last row of coef(summary(.x)).   `I tried .id = rownames(coef(summary(.x)))[nrow(coef(summary(.x)))` but that didn't work

Comment: Try renaming as `setNames(c("id","estimate","pvalue"))` then pipe to `%>% mutate(id = names(data)[id])` to refactor ids

Comment: I got this to work. Thanks for all the help. The data.table way @Roland mentioned is 9.7s vs. 62s (this method) .per 10,000 models.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll learn data.table one of these days.

Comment: i posted what I did.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the speedup is meaningful, but I've made some simplifications to your code.
First, call `factor` and `colnames(data)` just once outside the loop.

```
cov2 <- data.frame(cov1 = factor(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)))
#
cnames <- colnames(data)
mydata2 <- data.frame(cov2, outcome, other = NA)
```

Now, define a function to be used by `lapply`. Note that this function uses several data objects that exist in the global env, usually a bad practice.

```
fun <- function(i){
    id <- cnames[i]
    mydata2[, 3] <- data[, id]
    names(mydata2)[3] <- id
    fit <- glm(formula(paste0("outcome ~ cov1 + ", id)), data = mydata2)
    data.table(
        id = id,
        estimate = signif(coef(summary(fit))[id, "Estimate"], digits = 4),
        pvalue = signif(coef(summary(fit))[id, "Pr(>|t|)"], digits = 4)
    )
}

myresults2 <- rbindlist(lapply(seq_len(ncol(data)), fun))

identical(myresults, myresults2)
[1] TRUE
```

The object `myresults` is the one obtained by your code. As you can see, the results are identical.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer this is about 40 % faster:

```
timestart <- Sys.time()

mydata <- cbind(cov, outcome, data)
my.glm <- function (mycol) {
  fit <- glm(eval(parse(text = paste("outcome ~ cov1 +", mycol))), data = mydata)
    data.table(
    id = mycol,
    estimate = signif(coef(summary(fit))[mycol, "Estimate"], digits = 4),
    pvalue = signif(coef(summary(fit))[mycol, "Pr(>|t|)"], digits = 4)
  )
}
(res.l <- do.call(rbind, lapply(colnames(data), my.glm)))

Sys.time() - timestart
```